# How can I make an if else statement with python with and Y or N question

Tags: python, list

```
input("Y/N")
if input = Y:
    print("Heres the test")
else:
    print("I don't care heres a quiz for a lazy person")
```

I am trying to ask if they want to take a quiz if they say Y I want the quiz to appeare I want it to output heres a lazy person q`uiz.

Comment: Okay, cool. You've got a goal, and you've got some code. What's the problem? In what way does this code fail to do what you want? Please read [ask].

Comment: (There are at least three problems here, but you should really be looking at error messages—and sharing them—to figure out what needs to change.)

Comment: You really need to read a tutorial.  Try to (1) Learn the difference between the `=` assignment operator and the `==` comparison operator, and (2) Learn the difference between `Y`, which is a variable reference, and `"Y"`, which is a string, and (3) Learn how to assign the result of `input()` to a variable, rather than discarding it, and (4) Try to understand that `input` is a builtin function, and that it doesn't replace itself with the string the user entered as you seem to think.  To recap, the first line contains one bug, the second line contains three bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your question into a function and loop your main function within it. You do not need an `elif` statement. Else is perfectly fine:

```
def Please_format():
  your_code = input("Y/N")
  if your_code.startswith('y'):
    print("Heres the test") #your main function would go here 
  else:
    print("I don't care heres a quiz for a lazy person")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly You want to do. If You just want to print `"Heres the test"` on "Y" input and `"I don't care heres a quiz for a lazy person"` for any other inputs than You probably have to write a code such as :

```
user_input = input("Y/N")
if user_input == "Y":
    print("Heres the test")
else:
    print("I don't care heres a quiz for a lazy person")
```

If Your idea is to print `Heres the test` on "Y" input and `I don't care heres a quiz for a lazy person` on "N" input than You probably need some different code there :

```
user_input = input("Y/N")
    if user_input == "Y":
        print("Heres the test")
    elif user_input == "N":
        print("I don't care heres a quiz for a lazy person")
    else:
        print("Your input is not valid")
```

Ofcourse there are a lot of things may be done to improve the code such as type validation etc.